# is it safe to call setval of curval + 10 in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I use Postgres as a database for my java spring hibernate project.

To enable better performance in insert I use the pooled sequence which requires the database sequences to have an increment value equal to the pool size (let's say 10).

This causes multiple problems. Manual inserts, while working, need either to emulate the pooling algorithm, or to increment each insert by 10 using nextval as id each time.

The configuration is also more complex since each sequence needs to be configured (eg. can't use serial as is).
In addition, all server that insert into the table needs to have the same pool size, which force all the config to be synchronized with the database.

Would it be possible to implement a sequence algorithm that would make something like `setval('seq', curval('seq') + poolsize)` to let the server choose the pool size it wants, while maintaining the implicit contract that any number above curval is free to use. I am specifically inquiring about any concurrency problem of calling two methods to do what should be an atomic operation (eg. like AtomicInteger addAndGet).

This lead to my second question, is there any plugin of Postgres that would add this behaviour to the sequences? Since I know this behaviour is possible to implement.

Comment: Why not simply define the sequence with a `cache` size? I doubt that this "pooled sequence" will improve anything.

Comment: Cache size is also set. Without a pool Hibernate will generate nextval call for each entity to insert, even if the insert are batched. however small the cost of a nextval (with or without caching) it costs a round trip between database and server each time.

Comment: @SteveMarion Just checking... Are you sure it makes round trips for each insert even if you configure `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size`?

Comment: batch size will configure how much inserts will be batched together, but a nextval will be called for setting the ID anyway. I see it using ttddyy/datasource-proxy

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed method is vulnerable to a race condition.

Some options:

- You can pack your method into a PostgreSQL function and protect it against concurrent invocations with an *advisory lock*. This will of course only work if all use of the sequence is through the function.

  See [my blog](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/sequences-gains-and-pitfalls/) for details.
- You can define your sequence with a `CACHE` of 10. You don't get batches of variable size, but the sequence is only accessed every tenth time, and the values are cached in your database session.

  This is the most efficient way to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: concerning the cache, it does not change the fact that the server is unaware of this and it will still call nextval for each id it needs, even if internally the database is using a cache to get it. The function solution is interesting, but the lock will only block other function call, not the sequence itself ? My aim is to allow usage of default=nextval() for manual inserts

Comment: I don't understand your misgivings about `CACHE`. You only need a sequence value in an SQL statement, and then calling `nextval()` will be very cheap and not an extra client-server round trip. You don't call `SELECT nextval(...)` and then process that value in client code.